# How to run "decompiled NDK apk"

Tags: android-ndk, java-native-interface, shared-libraries

I am new to android ndk development. What i am trying to do is this :

**Step 1: Compiled my ndk app and got an apk**

**Step 2: i decompiled it with apktool and jdcompilers**

**Step 3: now i want to put it back together without any help of orignal code**

Comment: `jdcompilers` does not decompile the NDK parts. It's for Java bytecode decompilation; NDK code is neither Java nor bytecode.

Comment: yes. but can i use the compiled .so library and whatever i got after extracting apk without using my original source code.